# Why is $_REQUEST an empty array in admin-ajax.php?

Tags: php, ajax, uploads

I'm trying to upload files using AJAX and I'm hooking in my functions so they get called within admin-ajax. I can't get it to work tough, and I didn't have any idea what was wrong or where to look at all. I narrowed it down, however, by modifying admin-ajax.php a little bit:

```
// Require an action parameter
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) {
    $response = array(
        'error' => 'no action parameter',
        'req' => var_export( $_REQUEST, true )
    );
    wp_send_json( $response );
    wp_die( '0', 400 );
}
```

My AJAX request has dataType: 'json' in it, so my success function does get called(if I remove the $response declaration and the call to wp_send_json, the error one gets called, returning the entire page as a response with the statusText being "parsererror").

Anyway, here's my AJAX script:

```
    $( '#user-file' ).change( function( event ) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append( "userfile", $(this)[0].files[0] );
        formData.append( "action", "vibesoft_files_upload" );
        formData.append( "_wpnonce", vbsoft.nonce_upload );

        console.log( formData );

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: vbsoft.ajax_url,
            data: formData,
            contentType: "multipart/form-data",
            processData: false,
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function( data ) {
                if ( data.error != 'none' ) {
                    console.log( 'Error: ' + data.error );
                    console.log( 'Request: ' + data.req );
                    return;
                }
```

It's not the entire function, which is wrapped inside `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);` so I can use $ instead of jQuery. The `console.log( 'Request: ' + data.req );` outputs:

```
Request: array(
)
```

I also tried outputting the $_POST and $_FILES and they, too, are empty arrays. If I send them back using(instead of the JSON return):

```
var_dump( $_REQUEST );
exit;
```

I get `array(0) {}` back in the console.

So, yeah, I have no idea why am I getting an empty array...

Comment: I'd advise against using REQUEST, it contains a lot more than you think, including the contents of _COOKIE and _SESSION, use GET and POST explicitly for security reasons. Also have you considered using a REST API endpoint? The API is much more straight forward and you even get a pretty URL at the end

Comment: @TomJNowell The $_REQUEST is what admin-ajax.php uses, so I didn't want to modify it, but I will try it and will also look into REST API.

Comment: Can you post your answer as an answer rather than an edit of your question?

Comment: use request if you know what it does and know why it could be a security issue otherwise just don't use it.  it doesnt mean any one who uses it is doing it wrong of course.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append( "userfile", $(this)[0].files[0] );
    formData.append( "action", "vibesoft_files_upload" );
    formData.append( "_wpnonce", vbsoft.nonce_upload );

    console.log( formData );

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: vbsoft.ajax_url,
        data: formData,
```

Specifically:

```
    var formData = new FormData();
```

Nowhere in the jQuery documentation does it say that `data` accepts a `FormData` object for the `data` parameter:

> data Type: PlainObject or String or Array Data to be sent to the
>   server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.
>   It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to
>   prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If
>   value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key
>   based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

The solution is to instead use an object, e.g.:

```
var formData = {
    "userfile": $(this)[0].files[0],
    "action": "vibesoft_files_upload",
    "_wpnonce": vbsoft.nonce_upload
};
```

Keep in mind that if you'd used the much easier REST API, and specified the fields required, the API would have told you point blank what the problem was and which fields were missing. The REST API is much easier to use, with far fewer gotchas and hangups to trip over

So much so, there's already a core endpoint that might be able to do what you're trying to do, see https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/

Comment: I changed the formData to that, and this is what I'm getting back:
[Console Log](https://imgur.com/zwfHtYr)

Comment: hmmm I was wrong, this isn't a WP issue at all, it's a jQuery XHR AJAX issue, and your solution is actually over on stackoverflow at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

I ended up using the FormData object and changing the $.ajax call to:

```
$.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            data: form_data,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            url: custom.ajaxURL,
```